# Thymeleaf - setting attribute value with conditional

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I need to do something similar to this:

```
<div style="${flag ? 'block' : 'none'}"></div>
```

I have looked into `th:if` but couldn't find an appropriate way to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `th:style` instead of `style`, and the condition should be `${flag} ? 'val1' : 'val2'`. This should do the trick:

```
<div th:style="${flag} ? 'block' : 'none'"></div>
```